# MySQLi query returns only one row

Tags: php, mysqli, return, row

This code only returns one row, but it should return 2 rows. I have tried the SQL in phpMyAdmin and it perfectly returned 2 rows. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$request_list_result = $mysqli->query("
SELECT buddy_requester_id, buddy_reciepient_id, user_id, user_fullname FROM sb_buddies
JOIN sb_users ON buddy_requester_id=user_id
WHERE buddy_status='0' AND buddy_reciepient_id='". get_uid() ."'");

$request_list_row = $request_list_result->fetch_array();

echo $request_list['user_fullname'];
```

By the way, the code above is getting process to profile.php via following script:

```
$index = new Template('views/template/one.php', array(
'subtitle' => 'Dashboard',
'stylesheets' => array('/assets/css/profile.css'),
'scripts' => array('/assets/js/dashboard.js'),
'sidebar' => 'sidebar.php',
'content' => 'views/profile.php',
'errors' => $errors,
'successes' => $successes,
'request_list' => $request_list_row //right here
), true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through the results (as TheSmose mentioned)

```
while ($request_list_row = $request_list_result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $request_list['user_fullname'];
}
```

**AND** you need to send the resulting array `$request_list` to the template rather than `$request_list_row`.

**Change this**

```
'request_list' => $request_list_row //right here
```

**to this**

```
'request_list' => $request_list //right here
```

If you want more than just `user_fullname` in your template (and you don't have PHP >= 5.3 required for `mysqli_result::fetch_all`), then you will need to build up your own array inside the loop.

I don't know what your template code expects, but you could try

```
while ($request_list_row = $request_list_result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $request_list[] = $request_list_row;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 mysqli_result::fetch_array
```

only fetches a single row as an array, you are looking for

```
 mysqli_result::fetch_all
```

to fetch all the rows.

More info here

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: If i use fetch_all like following: $request_list_result->fetch_all();
It says: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the results.  As it stands, you're only fetching the first row.

```
$uid = get_uid();
$sql = "SELECT buddy_requester_id, buddy_reciepient_id, user_id, user_fullname 
        FROM sb_buddies
        JOIN sb_users ON buddy_requester_id=user_id
        WHERE buddy_status='0' AND buddy_reciepient_id='{$uid}'";

$request_list_result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($request_list_row = $request_list_result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $request_list['user_fullname'];
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I see your point, tried It but it does not work.
Please check my last edit, and se if that could have influence on your answer :-)